# Pass C++ object method as SDL_EventFilter

Tags: c++, callback, sdl

I am trying to create a game in C++ using SDL2, and of course I want to check for window resize events... since I have everything SDL-related handled by a `Game` class:

```cpp
bool Game::SetupSDL()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL initialization failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640, 480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL window creation failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (TTF_Init() < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_AddEventWatch(OnResize, window);

    return true;
}
```

Here is how `OnResize` is initialized:

```cpp
int Game::OnResize(void *data, SDL_Event *event)
{
    if (event->type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event->window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED)
    {
        SetScale();
        states[state]->OnResize(*this);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I attempt to compile it I get the following:

```
error: cannot convert 'Game::OnResize' from type 'int (Game::)(void*, SDL_Event*)' to type 'SDL_EventFilter {aka int (*)(void*, SDL_Event*)}'
  SDL_AddEventWatch(this->OnResize, window);
```

So it appears I´m having complications passing an instance method as an `SDL_FilterEvent` ... attempts to recast it have resulted in compile or runtime erros, how can I resolve this?

Comment: I am not familiar with this API, but you probably need to pass a static method (or a free function) as the callback, and pass your instance pointer (`this`) as the `void*` context. Then when you get the callback cast the `void*` context pointer back to `Game*` and call your method.

Comment: Non-static member functions needs an object to be called on (that becomes `this` inside the function). How would a C function know which object to use? It doesn't even know about C++ objects to begin with. Instead, if the callback system have things like user-data pointers, you could set the user-data pointer to point to the object, then use a *static* member function. This static member function takes the user-data pointer, converts it to a pointer to the object, and calls the actual non-static member function.

Comment: Read a bit more about this API. See my answer below.

Comment: @user12002570 I don't see how the duplicates you suggested actually relate to this issue. The OP seems to know how to pass a global function. The issue is using a non-static method with this specific API (which my answer below addresses). Voted to re-open.

Comment: @wohlstad I have reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

In order to register an event callback with [`SDL_AddEventWatch`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_AddEventWatch),
you need to supply a callback in the form of a function with the type [`SDL_EventFilter`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_EventFilter):

```
int (*SDL_EventFilter)(void *userdata, SDL_Event *event);
```

This should be either a free function, or a static method of a class. It cannot be a non-static method because such method requires a `Game` instance (the `this` pointer) in order to be invoked.

**A solution:**

In order to use a non-static method as a callback, you can utilize the `userdata` parameter to serve as your context.

When you register the event handler, pass `this` (i.e. a `Game*`) as `userdata` together with a static method:

```
static int Game::OnResizeEventCallback(void *userdata, SDL_Event *event);  // see implementation below

// ...

//---------------------------------------vvvvv-
SDL_AddEventWatch(OnResizeEventCallback, this);
```

Then when you get the callback convert `userdata` back to `Game*`, and call the non-static method:

```
static int Game::OnResizeEventCallback(void *userdata, SDL_Event *event)
{
    // Retrieve your instance:
    Game* pThis = reinterpret_cast<Game*>(userdata);
    // Call your non-static method with it:
    pThis->OnResize(event);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Mine assumed that passing the window pointer into SDL_AddEventWatch as in the OP's code shows, was correct - it is not.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting that error because the language doesn't know how to access the correct instance of the class to call the method on.

You can replace Game::OnResize with a free floating function outside of the Game class that has access to a pointer to your game instance, forwarding along the SDL event data, or you can use a static method within your Game class.

If you want to keep it all within your class (like I tend to do), you can replace Game::OnResize with a static method that has access to a pointer to your game, then create a new non-static method that actually does the processing of the event. The static method can then forward the event to the non-static method.

Like this:

```
// =========================================================================
// game.h
// =========================================================================

class Game
{
    public:
    
        // public stuff...
        
    private:
    
        // private stuff...
        
        // replace OnResize with this:
        static int OnSDLEvent(void *data, SDL_Event *event);
        
        // new function:
        int HandleSDLEvent(void *data, SDL_Event *event);
};

// =========================================================================
// game.cpp
// =========================================================================

// somewhere at the top...
Game *g_Game{}; // global pointer to the game, only in this file

Game::Game()
{
    // let's make g_Game point to our actual game instance
    // in your game's constructor.

    // or it could be in Game::SetupSDL() or wherever...
    // it just needs to happen before adding your event watch.

    // this is so the static method has an instance to work with.
    g_Game = this;
}


// here's the static method that gets called by SDL
int Game::OnSDLEvent(void *data, SDL_Event *event)
{
    // just pass along the event data.
    return g_Game->HandleSDLEvent(data, event);
}

// and here's where you actually handle the event!
int Game::HandleSDLEvent(void *data, SDL_Event *event)
{
    if (event->type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event->window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED)
    {
        SetScale();
        states[state]->OnResize(*this);
    }
    return 0;
}

// finally, feed SDL with our static method we created
bool Game::SetupSDL()
{
    // setup code here...

    // now we pass in our static method
    SDL_AddEventWatch(OnSDLEvent, window);

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to use a global `Game*` for the context. What if you have 2 `Game` instances (and you want each to get its callbacks) ?